# Variable in JS Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JSON Object

```
{scope:{results:{...}}}
```

And I have a String named

```
"data.one.url"
```

Now I want to set the value inside the JSON Object. Normally I would do it like this:

```
scope.results.data.one.url = "hello";
```

But how to do it when I only have the string mentioned above?

Comment: i don't understand what `to take the value inside the JSON Object what would be like` means..

Comment: Sorry I am german and ry this as best as I could. I try to make it clearer

Comment: @dfsq I use angular but I dont think it is important here. Correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's very important, because with Angular you can solve this problem in **one line** of code, because it already provides tool for string parsing and context resolution in `$parse` service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the data structure:

```
myData = {scope:{results:{data:{one:{url:"The url"}}}}}
```

Define a base. Your string access path is relative to this:

```
var base = myData.scope.results;
```

And a function to access by a path:

```
function getIn(base, path) {
  var components = path.split(".");
  var current = base;
  for (var i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
    current = current[components[i]];
  }

  return current;
}
```

And to use it:

```
getIn(base, "data.one.url")
>>> "The url"
```

Or relative to the root:

```
getIn(myData, "scope.results.data.one.url")
>>> "The url"
```

Of course more error handling is needed to make it robust to paths you don't expect.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and the most convenient way in this case (since you are using AngularJS) is to use `$parse` service:

```
var str = 'data.one.url';
var url = $parse('results.' + str)($scope); // "hello"
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/NYLvWc1gOA5X3glIM1gI?p=preview

Angular uses `$parse` service internally for exactly this sort of things. When you write in HTML `{{someobj.prop.name}}` the string `someobj.prop.name` is interpreted against `$scope` with the help of `$parse` service. It's very cool that you can use it yourself if you want. Just make sure to inject service into your controller.

Comment: In my code its actually a directive. How to inject it into the controller?

Comment: In case of directive: `.directive('myDirective', ['$parse', function($parse) { return { link: function() {}, controller: function() {} }; }])`.

Comment: Check the example of directive with injected $parse service: http://plnkr.co/edit/XEsj78I5k49ira2cp1X4?p=info

Answer (score -2):

how about this (if I get it well) ?

```
var myJSON = {scope:{results:{...}}}
myJSON["scope"]["results"]["url"] = data.one.url
myJSON = JSON.Stringify(myJSON);
```

then you would have this object as a JSON:
"{scope:{results:{url{value}}}}"

Comment: `{scope:{results:{url{"value"}}}}`  is not valid JSON. When data is encoded as JSON, the _key_ has to be double-quoted.  And this `url{"value"}` is also invalid.

Comment: thanks,I misused the term.

Comment: `url{value}` is still invalid.